# Как сделать модальное окно без блокировки родительского элемента?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Всем привет!
Как сделать модальное окно без блокировки родительского элемента?
Т.е. необходимо чтобы при нажатии на кнопку появилось сообщение о том что нажали кнопку, и через 2-3 секунды пропало, при этом пока горит это окно чтобы была возможность дальше пользоваться сайтом.

Comment: то есть необходимо создание не модального окна

Comment: https://sciactive.com/pnotify/   ........  https://quasar.dev/quasar-plugins/notify#api--notify  ..........https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Simple-Yet-Fully-Customizable-jQuery-Notification-Plugin-notify/...............https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/notification/ ........... https://colorlib.com/wp/jquery-notification-plugins/   ............. https://www.jqueryscript.net/tags.php?/Notification/

Comment: https://codepen.io/search/pens?q=notification+timer в помощь